# Simple Low Pass Filter for Boolean switch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, lowpass-filter

In a C# Class  need to filter out or ignore Boolean changes in an Update method if the interval between changes is too short.

In essence I need what is called a 'Low Pass Filter'

Lets say we have the following in either Update or FixedUpdate

```
if (myBoolean condition){
 myVal  =0;
}else{

 myVal= _rawInput;
}
```

What is happening is myBoolean condition in the above is switching too rapidly. I need to 'filter out' or ignore these short intervals.

I've tried using this LowPass Filter class for use with mobile accelerometer input but without luck since it assumes the value being filtered is a float.
 http://devblog.aliasinggames.com/accelerometer-unity/ Can anyone help?

Comment: You could have a static class variable of type timespan and set it to the current time if enough time has passed, comparing the current time - variable of type timespan, if the difference from current time - static timespan variable is not enough ignore doing your update. I'll post an answer below that explains what I'm suggesting.

Comment: @RyanWilson It took me longer to code it then you to write it up, but got the same idea :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yeah. I saw you beat me to the actual coding. Nice work, +1 from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LowPassFilter?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static bool MyValue = false;

    public static DateTime lastChange { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;

    public static void ChangeValue(bool b)
    {
        // do nothing if not 2s passed since last trigger AND the value is different
        // dont reset the timer if we would change it to the same value
        if (DateTime.Now - lastChange < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) || MyValue == b)
            return;
        // change it and remember change time
        lastChange = DateTime.Now;
        MyValue = b;
        Console.WriteLine($"Bool changed from {!b} to {b}. Time: {lastChange.ToLongTimeString()}");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            ChangeValue(!MyValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bool changed from False to True. Time: 23:29:23
Bool changed from True to False. Time: 23:29:25
Bool changed from False to True. Time: 23:29:27
```

The whole loop runs for about 7s - thats about 1.15 million triggers per second  to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it into a class:

```
public class FilteredBool
{
    private bool _inputValue;
    private bool _outputValue;
    private TimeSpan _minimumTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    private DateTime _lastChangeTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    public bool Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_outputValue != _inputValue)
            {
                if (_lastChangeTime + _minimumTime < DateTime.Now)
                    _outputValue = _inputValue;
            }
            return _outputValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_inputValue != value)
            {
                _inputValue = value;
                _lastChangeTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan MinimumTime
    {
        get { return _minimumTime; }
        set { _minimumTime = value; }
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(FilteredBool value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```

This has an implicit operator to `bool` so that you can just replace any function call that takes `bool` (or an `if`) without having to call `.Value`. There is no implicit operator back to `FilteredBool` because that would require setting a filter time. You can add this if you want, I felt that it would be a stretch to assume.

Comment: what purpose has the _outputvalue / the checks and modification inside the getter?

Comment: @PatrickArtner It was a typo in my code, I fixed it. The checks are in the getter because it really only matters when the value is being "get". The "_outputValue != _inputValue" makes sure that the inner check is only run once. You could take it out but it should be a little more performant not having to do date/time math each get.

Comment: But if I trigger your classes set method 10000 times a second, if will still flicker - what was the exact thing it should not do according to the Q? And after the time is over it might switch or not, depending on how often I triggered it? neat as well just the other way round :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner It won't "flicker", the input has to stay high (or low) for 5 seconds in order for the output value to change. You can set the "interval" that the OP is asking for (time it has to hold) by setting the `MinimumTime` property.

Answer (score 0):

OP
Thanks for the great solutions. As a quick hack for a Boolean low pass filter I was also wondering if it would be possible to simply use a counter and a Modulus operation, in essence 'slowing down' the FixedUpdate method. Boolean value can never change quicker than the interval of the modulus operation (or remainder) = zero. Haven't thought through implementation details. Thoughts?